# Calling from a list in c#

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to show the user the selection of movie they've made, however, I'm not sure how to call it from the list.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var movieList = new List<Movies>();

        //List of movies        
        movieList.Add ( new Movies {
        movieName = "Back to the Future",
        duration = 116});

        //Display all movies in list
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var Movie in movieList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}) Name: {1} | Duration: {2} mins",i, Movie.movieName, Movie.duration);
            i++;
        }

        //Selection of movie
        Console.Write("Please select a movie: ");
        var userMovieSelection = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

        Console.WriteLine("You've selected: {0} | {1} mins", [I'm having an issue here]

        Console.ReadKey(true);   
    }
}

public class Movies
{
    public string movieName {get; set;}
    public int duration {get; set;}
}
```

I've tried stuff like `movielist.movieName[userMovieSelection]` but keep getting errors such as there's no definition.

Comment: Because you've used `Movie` as the class name, you should use a different variable name `foreach (var movie in movieList)` to avoid confusion.

Comment: @jasen The class name is `Movies` though...

Comment: `var userMovieSelection = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;` what exactly are they supposed to be selecting here? what is `userMovieSelection`? Is that some kind of `id` property in the `Movie` class?

Comment: @Jasen but that does bring up the point.  OP _should_ name their class `Movie` not `Movies`.

Comment: @Jasen:  No the class name is Movies (should have been Movie though). The question is missing the exact error(s) that go with this version.

Comment: Console.WriteLine("You've selected: {0} | {1} mins", movieList[userMovieSelection].movieName,
movieList[userMovieSelection].duration])

Comment: Pressing a 1 at console, will return 49 (`Console.ReadKey().KeyChar`) To get the index you write the movies, you need `var userMovieSelection = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar- '0';`

Comment: your reading a char, the list needs an int

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
char userMovieSelection = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
int movieIndex = userMovieSelection - '0';
```

use `movieIndex` to access your list. Go easy on the `var` when you're new.

Comment: Yep worked! Thank you. I have to wait a few mins before I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

KeyChar is going to be a character or string.

```
try something like
int passed_index = 0;
string user_input =  Console.Read(); // Console.ReadKey().KeyChar
if (int.TryParse(user_input , out passed_index)) {
   if (passed_index < movieList.Count) {
     ; do stuff
   } else {
     ; let user know no items are there
   }
} else {
   ; ask user to input a number
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
        var isNumber = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var value);
        if (isNumber && value >= 0 && value < movieList.Count)
        {
            var userMovieSelection = Convert.ToInt32(value);
            var selectedMovie = movieList[userMovieSelection];
            Console.WriteLine("You've selected: {0} | {1} mins", selectedMovie.movieName, selectedMovie.duration);
        }
```

This will select the selected movie from the list. The full code is below.

**Update 1** - Included check that user enters valid number

**Update 2** - Included check that user enters an existing movie number

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // You can initialise movie list
        var movieList = new List<Movie>
        {
            new Movie
            {
                movieName = "Back to the Future",
                duration = 116
            }
        };

        //Display all movies in list
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var movie in movieList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("({0}) Name: {1} | Duration: {2} mins", i, movie.movieName, movie.duration);
            i++;
        }

        //Selection of movie
        Console.Write("Please select a movie: ");

        var isNumber = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var value);
        if (isNumber && value >= 0 && value < movieList.Count)
        {
            var userMovieSelection = Convert.ToInt32(value);
            var selectedMovie = movieList[userMovieSelection];
            Console.WriteLine("You've selected: {0} | {1} mins", selectedMovie.movieName, selectedMovie.duration);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect value entered");
        }
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Some notes on your code:

- I renamed the Movies class name to Movie, since it is just showing 1 movie
- In the foreach loop, you need to call the movie variable, not the movie class to get the name and duration
- To read the user number input, it's better if you use Console.ReadLine()

Comment: Plus 1 this is the only answer that fixes the OP's code, and works with integers greater than 9

Comment: Never pass a supposed number typed by your user directly to Convert.ToInt32. What happen if the user doesn' type a number? And what happen if the user types a number bigger than the number of movies in the list?

Comment: @johnny5  BTW: OP prints `:` for 11th movie. So expecting an input `:` is not wrong.

Comment: That's a lot better now. Just you don't need the conversion inside the if

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I updated the code to (1) check for both if a the value entered is a valid number, and (2) added another check to make sure that the movie number entered exists in the list

Comment: @L.B,  yes you can print ':' for the 11th movie, but what would use for the 191st movie? Too many people's answer focus on a problem that is described to us from someone who doesn't understand the core problem, and its note worth that it would be better to readline instead of char

Comment: @johnny5 I agree. Accepting  *best* answer depends on OP's knowledge (as in this case). I commented just becuase of this.

Answer (score 0):

Console.WriteLine("You've selected: {0} | {1} mins");

means nothing, {0} and {1} doesn't exists if they aren't in a foreach, you need to call the array index to call a List, here's the code to do it the right way:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo userMovieSelection = Console.ReadKey();

int userChoice = 0;

if (Int32.TryParse(userMovieSelection.KeyChar.ToString(), out userChoice))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You've selected: " + movieList[userChoice].movieName + " | " + movieList[userChoice].duration + " mins");
}
```